# R, how to compute an operation between dates on selected rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I am working in R on a dataframe which has the date of the first visit and/or of the last visit of a patient, this way:

| patient_ID | date | date_number | max_date_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2017-09-25 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 2019-03-05 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 2015-10-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 2010-04-15 | 1 | 7 |
| 6 | 2011-04-15 | 5 | 5 |

This table is contained in the `visits_dataframe` variable, computed this way:

> visits_dataframe <- data.frame(patient_ID=integer(), date=character(),  date_number=character(),  max_date_number=character())
>
> patients <- c(3,3,5,6,6)
>
> dates <- c("2017-09-25", "2019-03-05", "2015-10-01", "2010-04-15", "2011-04-15")
>
> date_numbers <- c("1","7","1","1","5")
>
> max_date_numbers <- c("7","7","1","7","5")
>
> visits_dataframe <- data.frame(patients, dates, date_numbers, max_date_numbers, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

I need to compute the average date distance between the first visit and the last visit, when available, for all the patients. That would be the total duration of the therapy for each patient.

In this example, I would like to compute the distance between 2019-03-05 and 2017-09-25  for the `3` patient, and between 2011-04-15 and 2010-04-15 for the `6` patient.
In this example, I would not be able to compute it for the `5` patient, because the `max_date_number` is unavailable for her/him.

I tried this piece of code but did not work:

> visits_dataframe_durations <- ave(visits_dataframe$date_number, visits_dataframe$patient_ID, FUN = (visits_dataframe[(visits_dataframe$date_number==1),] - visits_dataframe[(visits_dataframe$date_number==max_date_number),]))

Basically, I have to use a command that says:

> for each patient ID:
>
> - find the last visit date (`date_number == max_date_number`)
> - find the first visit date  (`date_number == 1`)
> - compute the distance between last visit and first visit (`thisDuration`)
> - save this duration into a general duration variable (`generalDuration += thisDuration`)
>
> end for
>
> compute average duration = general duration / number of patients

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
visits_dataframe %>%
     mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>%
     group_by(patients) %>%
     mutate(durations = dates[date_numbers == 1] - 
                dates[date_numbers == max_date_numbers])
```